# how to actually use ical in spring

Tags: java, spring, icalendar

I've been try to use ical in spring now i have implement two files, one for create an event another one for sent email after the event created.

here is my code:

```
public class cal {
public static String mailfrom = "example@mail.com";
public static String mailto = "example@mail.com";

public static Multipart getContent() throws Exception {
    // create a timezone
    TimeZoneRegistry registry = TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry();
    TimeZone timezone = registry.getTimeZone("United Kingdom/Bristol");
    VTimeZone vTimeZone = timezone.getVTimeZone();
    //event start
    java.util.Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    startDate.setTimeZone(timezone);
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, java.util.Calendar.MARCH);
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //event end
    java.util.Calendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    endDate.setTimeZone(timezone);
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, java.util.Calendar.MARCH);
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //instance
    String eventName = "testifwork";
    DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate.getTime());
    DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate.getTime());
    VEvent meeting = new VEvent(start, end, eventName);
    //add timezone
    meeting.getProperties().add(vTimeZone.getTimeZoneId());
    //generate unique uid
    UidGenerator uidGenerator = new RandomUidGenerator();
    Uid uid = uidGenerator.generateUid();
    meeting.getProperties().add(uid);
    //add attendee
    Attendee attendee1 = new Attendee(URI.create("mailto:example@mail.com"));
    attendee1.getParameters().add(Role.REQ_PARTICIPANT);
    attendee1.getParameters().add(new Cn("develop 1"));
    meeting.getProperties().add(attendee1);

    Attendee attendee2 = new Attendee(URI.create("mailto:example@mail.com"));
    attendee1.getParameters().add(Role.REQ_PARTICIPANT);
    attendee1.getParameters().add(new Cn("develop 2"));
    meeting.getProperties().add(attendee2);

    Attendee attendee3 = new Attendee(URI.create("mailto:example@mail.com"));
    attendee1.getParameters().add(Role.REQ_PARTICIPANT);
    attendee1.getParameters().add(new Cn("develop 3"));
    meeting.getProperties().add(attendee3);
    //create calendar
    net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar icsCalendar = new Calendar();
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(Method.REQUEST);
    // add the event
    icsCalendar.getComponents().add(meeting);
    //make it binary
    CalendarOutputter calendarOutputter = new CalendarOutputter(false);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    calendarOutputter.output(icsCalendar, outputStream);
    byte[] mailbyte = outputStream.toByteArray();
    BodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); //Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions
    mimeBodyPart.setContent(mailbyte, "text/calendar;method=REQUEST;charset=UTF-8");
    MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
    mimeMultipart.setSubType("related"); // relate is Embedded Resource
    mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
    return mimeMultipart;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    //mail protocol
    properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    //url
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //account
    Authenticator authentication = new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            String user = properties.getProperty("user","example@mail.com");
            String password = properties.getProperty("password","password");
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
        }
    };
    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(properties, authentication);
    Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    try {
        //mail from
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailfrom));
        //mail to
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mailto));
        //mail time
        message.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());
        //mail heading
        String subject = "test";
        message.setSubject(subject);

        Multipart multipart = getContent();
        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.saveChanges();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
    }
    System.out.println(sendmail(message));
}

public static Boolean sendmail(Message message) {
    //sent mail
    try {
        Transport.send(message);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //mail invalid
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

second one:

```
public class email {
public static void main(String[] args){
    sendEmail();
}

private static Properties properties;
private static Session session;

public static void sendEmail(){
    try {
        String name = "name";

        properties = new Properties();
        String mailfrom = properties.getProperty("mail@example.com");
        String mailto = properties.getProperty("mail@example.com");
        properties.put("mail.imap.port", "25");
        properties.put("mail.imap.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                String user = properties.getProperty("user","mail@example.com");
                String password = properties.getProperty("password","password");
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
            }
        };
        session  = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailfrom));
        mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailto));
        mimeMessage.setSubject("is a test");


        String startTime = getUtc("2020-04-10 14:00");
        String endTime = getUtc("2020-04-10 16:00");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String buffer = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n"
                + "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n"
                + "VERSION:2.0\n"
                + "METHOD:REQUEST\n"
                + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n"
                + "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"+"mail@example.com"+"\n"
                + "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:"+"mail@example.com"+"\n"
                + "DTSTART:" + startTime + "\n"
                + "DTEND:" + endTime + "\n"
                + "LOCATION: emergency department\n"
                + "UID:" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "\n"
                + "CATEGORIES:\n"
                + "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" + "BEGIN:VALARM\n"
                + "TRIGGER:-PT15M\n" + "ACTION:DISPLAY\n"
                + "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" + "END:VALARM\n"
                + "END:VEVENT\n" + "END:VCALENDAR";
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer,"text/calendar;method=REQUEST;charset=\"UTF - 8\"")));
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mimeBodyPart.setText("name:" + name);
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);
        mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
        mimeMessage.saveChanges();
        Transport.send(mimeMessage);


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getUtc(String string){
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm");
    long second = 0;
    try {
        second = simpleDateFormat.parse(string).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long currentTime = second + 60 * 60 * 1000;
    Date date = new Date(currentTime);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    String nowTime;
    nowTime = dateFormat.format(date);
    return nowTime.replace("-","").replace(" ", "T").replace(":","");
}
```

}

now i'm not sure how to actually use them in spring, should i use them in controller or application. How exactly should i implement it? Is there needed to have a ics file manually or should i do that in first file

Comment: What are you actually trying to acompplish ? What's the goal?

Comment: @Matis I'm trying to use it to generate the ics file and abe to sent to user